# mvc 5 Active Directory authentication with login for restricted users only

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, active-directory, owin

I managed to create MVC5 web application with Active Directory validation. But I want to restrict login to application only for certain users. How can I achive this?

Is it possible that I can insert to table AspNetUser with restricted users and then allow only these users to log in to website.

Comment: Is your server inside the AD? Are you using identity or windows auth?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a filter like I use: (this filters by group)

```
 public class AuthorizeADAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private readonly IUserProfileRepository _userProfileRepository;

    /// <summary>
    /// this comes from the web.config
    /// </summary>
    public string Groups { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Override the authorization routine to check if this user is part of 'AllowedOUs' (web.config key; comma delimited)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="httpContext"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext))
        {
            /* Return true immediately if the authorization is not 
            locked down to any particular AD group */
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Groups))
                return true;

            // Get the AD groups
            var groups = Groups.Split(',').ToList();

            // Verify that the user is in the given AD group (if any)
            var context = new PrincipalContext(
                                  ContextType.Domain,
                                  WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AllowedDomain"]);

            var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
                                   context,
                                   IdentityType.SamAccountName,
                                   httpContext.User.Identity.Name);
            try
            {
                foreach (var group in groups)
                {
                    if (userPrincipal.IsMemberOf(context,
                         IdentityType.Name,
                         group))
                    { return true; }
                }                   
            }
            catch //(Exception ex)
            {
                // not in group
                // will fail through to non-authorized page
                // can log 'hack' attempts if necessary
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// redirect on failure
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext"></param>
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(
    AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var result = new ViewResult();
            result.ViewName = "NotAuthorized";
            result.MasterName = "_Layout";
            filterContext.Result = result;
        }
        else
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

And then on any class/method, decorate accordingly:

```
[AuthorizeAD(Groups = "Implementation Development")]
public class UserProfileController : Controller
{...
```